# Search XML File with Multiple Attributes with Match Case

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, xpath

How to search with multiple child node values with Match Case by using XPath in XML File.
I have below XML file.

```
<catalog>
  <book id="BK-1001">
    <title>C# 2005 Programmer's Reference</title>
    <author>Adrian Kignsley</author>
    <genre>.NET</genre>
    <price>0</price>
    <publish_date>2006-11-1</publish_date>
    <description>This is reference book.</description>
  </book>
  </catalog>
```

And I want to search based on title, author and genre with Match Case. I'm using this expression:

```
"book[title='" + strInputString_1 + "'] | book[author='" + strInputString_2 + "'] | book[genre='" + strInputString_3 + "']"
```

But, it didn't working. How I can do this ?

Comment: do you only want to use with xpath how about linq to xml

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `//` in the beginning of the XPath.

```
"//book[title='" + strInputString_1 + "'] | //book[author='" + strInputString_2 + "'] | //book[genre='" + strInputString_3 + "']"
```

You can try this although:

```
"//book/title[.='" + strInputString_1 + "'] | //book/author[.='" + strInputString_2 + "'] | //book/genre[.='" + strInputString_3 + "']"
```